# C++ code Compatibility with Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, native, native-code

I have a c++ code which is needed to communicate with an OCR scanner. On Windows it works fine. However I need to integrate it with Android. My approach is to use the NDK and JNI. However the problem is that the c++ code is only compatible with Windows (There are endless dependencies on windows libraries). When I try to build it using the NDK, it fails.

Any suggestion regarding this? Should try to convert the code to a linux compatible one? OR is there another way?

Note: the code calls a dll library that contains the functions to communicate with the scanner.

Comment: This isn't likely going to work easily ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ any hint? Should I try to write my own code? (this would be time consuming, it's a scanner specific code). Or is there any way around?

Comment: @user1851212: This may very well turn out to be a huge project lasting many months. And without any details, it's impossible to tell. It's like asking "I have program X which works fine on Windows. How can I convert it to Linux?"

Comment: IMHO trying to find a Linux version of your scanner driver would be a start. The manufacturer probably has some input on this.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.